# How to Minimize code using loops and should not repeat random numbers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

I have 18 Gameobject and i want to position all 18 gameobject in defined random position. yes i said defined position as my gameobjects z position will only change randomly like [0,60, 120, 180 and so on] randomly. please help.

```
GameObject[] hurdles;
int randShared;

void Shart()
    {
        hurdles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Hurdles");
        randShared = Random.Range(0,19);

        if (randShared == 0)
        {
            hurdles[0].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            hurdles[1].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 60f);
            hurdles[2].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 120f);
            .
            .
            .
            hurdles[18].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 120f);
        }

        if (randShared == 1)
        {
            hurdles[0].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 120f);
            hurdles[1].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            hurdles[2].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 60f);
            .
            .
            .
            hurdles[18].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 120f);
        }

        if (randShared == 2)
        {
            hurdles[0].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 60f);
            hurdles[1].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 120f);
            hurdles[2].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            .
            .
            .
            hurdles[18].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 120f);
        }

        .
        .
        .

        if (randShared == 18)
        {
            hurdles[0].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 60f);
            hurdles[1].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 120f);
            hurdles[2].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            .
            .
            .
            hurdles[18].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 120f);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your range and create an offset in intervals of 60, based on your random number.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    var offset = i + randShared;
    if (offset > 18)
    {
        offset = offset - 19;
    }

    hurdles[i].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, (float)(offset * 60));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rnd = new Random();
for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    hurdles[i].transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 60f * rnd.Next(4)));
```

Comment: its working but not for random, this code generates zPos in sequence. only first one is random according to randShared. I want random zPos. @Zdravko Danev

Comment: Its showing error, Type `UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for `Next' and no extension method `Next' of type `UnityEngine.Random' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? @Zdravko Danev

Comment: change it to System.Random

Comment: Ok, Now error is gone. but all hurdles came at next 4 position rest 14 positions are empty :(